# Unexpected token ' : ' on a where clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am making a where clause using sequilize and for some reason I am getting an unexpected token out of it. This is my code:

```
where: {
    [op.and]: [db.sequelize.literal(`\`subcategories\`.\`category_id\` IS NOT NULL`), '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId]
  }
```

Can someone help me to format the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where: {
    [op.and]: [db.sequelize.literal(`\`subcategories\`.\`category_id\` IS NOT NULL`), { '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId }]
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Do you think tou can give me a quick help on something? I am trying to make my where clause optional, meaning if the categoryId is null I want to show everything. Can you help me on this?

Comment: `const where = { }
if (categoryId) {
 where[op.and] = [db.sequelize.literal(`\`subcategories\`.\`category_id\` IS NOT NULL`), { '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId }]
}`
and then indicate it as `where: where` or simply `where`

Comment: const where = {}
    if (categoryId) {
        where: {
            '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId
        } }

Comment: I want do do something like this, problem is that syntax '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId  is giving me an error -> ':' expected

Comment: const where = {} if (categoryId) { where = { '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId } }

Comment: Last question sorry,can this be done outside the findAll()? like this is a N-M relation,and wanted to know I can access the $subcategories.category_id$ outside the findAll

Comment: That statement is giving me a ( UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Assignment to constant variable)

Comment: Sorry, it should be let where = {}

Comment: No worries :D Do you think you can take a lookt into this questions -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282783/how-to-pass-object-as-a-data-type-to-a-data-model-in-sequilize

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it should work

```
where: {
[op.and]: [db.sequelize.literal(`\`subcategories\`.\`category_id\` IS NOT NULL`), { '$subcategories.category_id$': categoryId }]
}
```