# How to pass object as a data type to a data model in sequilize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I need to pass something that is not a primitive to the data type.

I am constructing something like this to send to the create method:

```
const p2 = {
          location_model: {
          latitude: lat,
           longitude: lng
      },
        establishment_id: createdEstablishment.id
      }
```

As you can see the establishment_id is of type Integer but the location_model is an object

This is my model

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('EstablishmentLocation', {
      location_model: {
        type: // need some datatype that accept's an object of that type
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Location',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
      establishment_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        references: {
          model: 'Establishment',
          key: 'id',
        },
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.STRING,
      }
    });
  },

  down: (queryInterface) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('EstablishmentLocation');
  }
};
```

My question is, how can I pass an object to a data type in sequilize?

Comment: @akash-dathan is right see his answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type` you provide in the model are the types defined in the database you use. If you are using `postgresql`, you can use `DataTypes.JSON` as the type.

If not, to save object, you can `JSON.stringify` the object and pass it as a string.

Comment: Thanks :D  Im learning so much with you guys. Can you also help me in this one ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308665/how-to-make-multiple-where-clauses-for-the-same-row)