# How to make multiple where clauses for the same row?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to make multiple Where / AND clauses for the same row: This is my request body

```
"sub_categories":[
        {
            "category_id":2
        },
        {
            "category_id":1
        }

    ]
```

This is my javascript code

```
var where = {}
if (subcategories != undefined) {
    subcategories.forEach(async (item) => {
        where['$subcategories.id$'] = item.category_id
    });
}
```

Expected query to produce :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where sub_categories .category_id = 1 AND sub_categories .category_id = 2
```

Questy that is given to me :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE where sub_categories .category_id = 2 (Last one)
```

Do I need to add something to the code in order to do this?

Comment: How can `.category_id` be equal to both 1 and 2 at the same time?

Comment: subcategory id refers to establishment's, so I may want to find one that fit's in 2 subcategories. And that's why

Comment: did not gave that part of the context. But just assume I need this. Am I making any syntax error on this?

Comment: so does each row have a list of subcategory ids?

Comment: yes exactly that

Comment: each establishments has a row of subcategories[ ]

Comment: do you know how to help me @SimonCrane?

Comment: In your js code $subcategories.id$ just get over written in every iteration.

Comment: do you have a way to prevent that? @AkashDathan

Comment: Its the issue with your query, try running your query in your db, it will fail. Do you need a 'and' query or an 'or' query ?

Comment: "and" query in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var where = {}
if (subcategories != undefined && subcategories.length) {
   where['$and'] = []
    subcategories.forEach((item) => {
        where['$and'].push({
           '$subcategories.id$': item.category_id
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: let me try it out

Comment: Invalid value { '$subcategories.id$': 1 }, gives me this error @Anatoly

Comment: Yeah this is not working. I can't remove the [$and]

Comment: "Error: Invalid value { '$subcategories.id$': 1 } @Analoty

Comment: if you want me to accept this question please remove the where['$and'] from it, because this way it doesn't work (only when you remove it] . Also if you can help me in this one [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61311414/how-to-add-or-statement-in-the-where-clause-using-sequilize]

Comment: after this code 'where; should be like this:
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "$subcategories.id$": 1
    },
    {
      "$subcategories.id$": 2
    }
  ]
}